# pd.read_excel process/thread safe?

Tags: pandas, multithreading, multiprocessing, thread-safety

Can multiple processes/threads call pd.read_excel on the same excel file safely?  I know it is not safe to read and write with multiple threads/processes on the same excel file but is read-only ok?

Thanks

Comment: But why? Read it once, then process it in different threads.

Comment: For practical purposes, it cannot be done this way (processes in external servers call the function that needs to read the file throughout the day).

Is there a data format that other than excel that is safe for concurrent reads?  I know reading and writing concurrently is problematic but what about simply reading

Comment: I'm almost sure that if you are reading from different machines, you're safe, at least from the pandas/python point of view. I think it could be useful if you add details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `pandas.read_excel` is thread-safe because it's blocking in the sense that it will guarantee that only one sheet will be read at the same time.

So you will not see any nasty thread-safety related errors, but you will also not see any speed up from running multiple threads.